# zoom image inside the viewpazer and sliding

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have code that slides images one by one as I passed pager adapter in pager and an array of that imaged, help me for zooming that images,i put the code of zooming but it is not working,

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.braidfullimage);
    
    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();
    
    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_braid);
    barid_adapter imageAdapter = new barid_adapter();
    pager.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    
    pager.getCurrentItem();
    
    
    /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.braid_full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);*/
}
   class barid_adapter extends PagerAdapter {
       private static final String TAG = "Touch";
       // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

       // We can be in one of these 3 states
       static final int NONE = 0;
       static final int DRAG = 1;
       static final int ZOOM = 2;
       int mode = NONE;

       // Remember some things for zooming
       PointF start = new PointF();
       PointF mid = new PointF();
       float oldDist = 1f;
    
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.dss, R.drawable.hygienicbraid,/* R.drawable.daniellayaki,*/
            /*R.drawable.hygienicbraid, R.drawable.loosedeep,
            R.drawable.yakicurl, */
    };

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
      @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
          Context context = FullImageActivity.this;
         
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
          imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
          imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                  // Dump touch event to log
                  dumpEvent(event);

                  // Handle touch events here...
                  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                     start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                     Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                     mode = DRAG;
                     break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                     oldDist = spacing(event);
                     Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                     if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                     }
                     break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                     mode = NONE;
                     Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                     break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                     if (mode == DRAG) {
                        // ...
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                              event.getY() - start.y);
                     }
                     else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                           matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                           float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                           matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        }
                     }
                     break;
                  }

                  view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                  return true; // indicate event was handled
               }
        });
          
          
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
        }
      
      private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          int action = event.getAction();
          int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
          sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
          if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
             sb.append("(pid ").append(
                   action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
             sb.append(")");
          }
          sb.append("[");
          for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
             sb.append("#").append(i);
             sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
             sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
             sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
             if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
          }
          sb.append("]");
          Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
       }

       /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
       private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
          return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
       }

       /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
       private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
          point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
       }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }
     @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problem : Imagview zoom will not work properly if you are using it inside viewpager as viewpager also will have own slide feature.

**Solution:** If you want to still make this type of feature then you can do one thing. make the custom viewpager which will be nonswipable by below way. add two buttons in your view for left-right and change the screen on click of that buttons. rest of things would be as it is.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for advice ,but i need swaping in fullscreen as well as zooming also swaping is good using this code but  zooming of that image is not happening ....

Comment: @user2126135 : AFAIK you need to rethink again for this thing. you can also disable swiping on longpress of image. and after user can pinch zoom on it. after again long press you can enable swiping and user will not able to zoom on picture.